# SQL Query Theory Question

Tags: sql, sql-server, query-tuning

I have a large historical transaction table (15-20 million rows MANY columns) and a table with **one row one column**.  The table with one row contains a date (last processing date) which will be used to pull the data in the trasaction table ('process_date').

Question: Should I inner join the 'process_date' table to the transaction table or the transaction table to the 'process_date' table?

Comment: I would be very surprised if it would result in different execution plans.

Comment: Just checked with two of our tables. It returns the exact same execution plan. To answer your question, it doesn't matter.

Comment: Does the execution plan have a direct correlation to efficientcy?  That is if 2 plans are exactly the same is the execution time exactly the same?

Comment: If there's really only ever going to be one row/column in the table then I probably wouldn't `JOIN` at all, I'd `SELECT` the value into a variable and then write `WHERE process_date = @last_process_date`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is how I would do it

```
SELECT <<list only columns you need>> 
FROM large_historical_transaction_table t
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM OneRowTable o 
              WHERE o.last_processing_date = t.process_date)
```

Comment: I'm sure you know what you're talking about, with a name like SQLMenace and a rep of 17k, but on first glance, it looks like correlated subquery will be executed for each row in the large table?

Comment: +1, @mdma, it looks that way, but this is faster than the regular join

Comment: Thanks for clarification. I'm interested to get into the details of how it's faster - do you know of links describing this in more detail?

Comment: @mdma: Generally speaking, a `JOIN` implies returning **all** matching rows whereas `EXISTS` only needs to find the first one.  Although in this case it doesn't matter because there's only one row in the lookup table to begin with.

Comment: +1, even though I don't get it! @Aaronaught - I kind of see where you are coming from, but here there is only one row, so what's the actual difference in practice?

Comment: I just tried this in SQL server. Using an INNER JOIN and the subselect - the actual query plans are identical, so the subquery wasn't faster.

Comment: @mdma: With only one row, there probably is no difference in practice.  Still, it's good to get into the habit of using `IN` or `EXISTS` when you don't actually need a true `JOIN` - oftentimes (but not always) it will lead to a more efficient plan.  Especially on, shall we say, *differently-abled* DBMSes like mysql.

Comment: Differently-abled! hehe! :-) Thanks for the advice, I'll keep that in mind. I kind of have a wired in knee jerk reaction when relating two tables to use a join, I'll have to unlearn that habit.

Answer (score 3):

An Inner join is a symmetrical, bi-directional relationship, in general it doesn't matter, but in this case I would suggest not joining at all, read the threshold date into a variable and pass it to the other select query as a parameter...

Answer (score 2):

For readability I would inner join from the transaction table to explicitly indicate that the second table with the date just acts like a filter.

Answer (score 2):

When joining tables, the query optimizer takes a quick sniff of both to determine the most appropriate join implementation. Logically the inner join is symmetric, but the implementation may favor one side over the other for improved performance.